# Filtering None when summing variables from entrybox

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to perform a simple Sum of entry box values but have not been able to effectively deal with None by either ignoring it when summing or have it = 0. The latest option I am trying is the filter. However, I was told this could also be done with the dictionary or Walrus Operator to each of the variables. I have not gotten any of them to work.

Here is my code:

```
 def sum(self):
        self.atotalcost_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        a = int(float(self.cost102_entry.get()))
        b = int(float(self.cost103_entry.get()))
        c = int(float(self.cost112_entry.get()))
        d = int(float(self.cost130_entry.get()))
        e = int(float(self.cost149_entry.get()))
        f=  int(float(sum(filter(None,(a,b,c,d,e)))))
        self.atotalcost_entry.insert(0,format_money(Money(f,USD),locale='en_US'))
```

Here is what I've tried with Filter:

```
f=  int(float(sum(filter(None,(a,b,c,d,e)))))
```

I get the error could not convert string to float: None:

I've also tried short-circuiting:

```
a = int(float(self.cost102_entry.get() or 0))
```

Same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by putting the widgets in a list. Note that if you put the widgets in a list when you first create them you can avoid this step.

```
entries = (
    self.cost102_entry,
    self.cost103_entry,
    self.cost112_entry,
    self.cost130_entry,
    self.cost149_entry,
)
```

Next, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get the values of all non-empty widgets, converting each to a float:

```
values = [float(entry.get()) for entry in entries if entry.get()]
```

Note: this isn't the only way - you can indeed use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) if you wish, though it's arguably a bit more complicated. Also, this step assumes the values are all able to be converted to a float.

If you are unfamiliar or uncomfortable with list comprehensions, a normal loop can be used with just a couple extra lines of code. This also makes it easy to add error checking if you wish. To keep the example simple and functionally identical to the list comprehension, I've left that out of the following example.

```
values = []
for entry in entries:
    s = entry.get()
    if s:
        values.append(float(s))
```

Now, use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to calculate the sum:

```
print(f"sum:", {sum(values)}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will implement this and then be back to mark this the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I am still getting the same error. ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'. I may have to handle this on the DB side since I get this same error no matter what I try.

Comment: @MelanieLauzon: you must be leaving some details out. `.get()` will never return `None`, I think it's literaly impossible. `.get()` should always return a string. I've updated my examples to handle the case where `.get()` returns `None`, though I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: Finally I got it to work. I had to change != '' to != 'None'.

Comment: @MelanieLauzon: so, you're getting the literal four-byte string "None"?  Your question wasn't very clear on that point. I thought you were getting python's `None` value.